# what will happen if I remove runat="server" from newly added web control

Tags: asp.net

what will happen if I remove runat=server from newly added web control

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to access it directly via the server (aspx.cs event), so you will need to handle it with Request.Form["param"] at the page load (submit)

> "The runat="server" attribute indicates that the form should be
>   processed on the server. It also indicates that the enclosed controls
>   can be accessed by server scripts"

For more details: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp